# Playing sound while tweening

Tags: java, libgdx, tween

I've run into an issue while trying to implement an idea I have.

I have an image that I tween the alpha layer of, fading it in and a second later fading it out. Here I wish to play a mario coin at the point of total fade in.

I've tried implementing different callbacks for this but either way I do it the sound plays either before the tweening or after the tweening.

Code snippet:

```
Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager);
Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 0.5f).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
        ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
    }
}).start(tweenManager);
```

doing:

```
Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager);
Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 0.5f).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
        SoundManager.PlayIntro();
        ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
    }
}).start(tweenManager);
```

Plays the sound after the tweening.

And:

```
Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager)
    .setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
                SoundManager.PlayIntro();
            }
    });

Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 0.5f).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
        ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
    }
}).start(tweenManager);
```

Plays before. How do I implement a what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a Timeline from the tween engine and creating a sequence, it's what I use the most for these cases.

This should work for you:

```
Timeline.createSequence().beginSequence()
        .push(Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 0).target(0))
        .push(Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
                SoundManager.PlayIntro();
            }
        }))
        .pushPause(0.5f)
        .push(Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2f).target(0)).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
            }
        })
.start(tweenManager);
```

Comment: Amazing! Wasn't aware of the timeline feature. Thanks a lot!